# Linear algebra, Approximation and fundamental theorem of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ find $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ which is a solution to $A\vec{y}=0$ and is a minimum distance from $\vec{x}$.

Show that for $\vec{y}$ such that $A\vec{y}=0$ and $\left \| \vec{x}-\vec{y} \right \|$ is as small as possible, then $\vec{x}-\vec{y}$ is in the $Row(A)$.

I am very close to this, can someone help me clear my thoughts a bit?
Here is my process,
because $A\vec{y}=0$ and $\vec{y}$ is in $R^n$  so $\vec{y}$ is in the Null(A),
x-ay=x-projection of x onto Col(A), which is equal to perp ColA (x) – Logan 6 mins ago

So $\vec{x}-A\vec{y}$ is in the complement of Row space of A, using "the fundamental theorem of linear algebra" again.
How do you go from there? Please help me!!!!

Comment: I suggest that first you show us *how* close you are.

Comment: So y is in the Null space of (A), right? and because of Ay=0 then using "the fundamental theorem of linear algebra, y is also in the complement of Row space of A

Comment: Then, x-ay=x-projection of x onto Col(A), which is equal to perp ColA (x)

Comment: So x-Ay is in the complement of Row space of A, using "the fundamental theorem of linear algebra" again.

Comment: How do you go from there?

Comment: What I was suggesting was that you *edit your question* to show us how close you are.

Comment: Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in what you've written, but you essentially have the idea for the second question.

We are looking for the point $\vec y$ in the nullspace of $A$ that is as close to $\vec x$ as possible, which is in other words the projection of $\vec x$ onto the nullspace of $A$. By the properties of orthogonal projection, such a $\vec y$ has the property that $\vec x - \vec y$ lies in the orthogonal complement to the nullspace of $A$.

By the fundamental theorem, this is the same as saying that $\vec x - \vec y$ lies in the row space of $A$.

---

As for how to compute this vector: note that the matrix that projects onto the row space of $A$ is given by $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ (assuming the rows of $A$ are linearly independent). It follows that the projection onto the nullspace has the matrix
$$
P = I - A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A.
$$
The vector that we are after is the projection of $\vec x$ onto the nullspace, which will simply be $\vec y = P \vec x$.

---

If the rows of $A$ are not linearly independent, we can proceed as follows. The projection of $\vec x$ onto the row-space of $A$ is the vector $A^T \vec z$, where $\vec z$  is the least squares solution to the equation $A^T \vec z = \vec x$. In other words, if $\vec z$ is any solution to the equation
$$
AA^T \vec z = A \vec x,
$$
then $A^T \vec z$ is the projection of $\vec x$ onto the row space. It follows that the desired vector $\vec y$ is equal to $\vec y = \vec x - A^T\vec z$.

Comment: How do you get "By the properties of orthogonal projection, such a y⃗  has the property that x⃗ −y⃗  lies in the orthogonal complement to the nullspace of A." ????

Comment: @Logan If $\vec y$ is the projection of $\vec x$ onto a subspace $U$, then $\vec x - \vec y$ must be an element of the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$. This is a property that is almost certainly stated explicitly somewhere in your textbook

Comment: I get it that x-Ay is in The row space of A, and so because Ay=0, then does Ay=y??

Comment: @Logan I don't know how you came to that conclusion. It is not true that $x - Ay$ is necessarily in the row space of $A$.

Comment: so Ay=Projection of x onto the Null(A), right?

Comment: @Logan No. I don't know why you think so

Comment: Then, x-Ay=x-proj of x onto Null(A)= perp x onto Null(A),

Comment: okay, never mind, something must be wrong here with my brain...,Thank you!

Comment: @Logan No judgment. I just wanted to know if there was a specific false belief that led to this conclusion

Comment: I was thinking about the projection of x onto the Col(A), which is wrong..., I understand it now.

Comment: @Logan Makes sense, glad we cleared tha up

Comment: Hi, why is it this system? $AA^T\vec{z}=A\vec{x}$  ?   I think this is wrong? maybe? Shouldn't it be $A^TA\vec{z}=A^T\vec{y}$???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115598/discussion-between-logan-and-ben-grossmann).

Comment: You're confusing the row space and column space

Comment: It's perfect clear now, I got it, you are correct, Thank you so much!